# How to smooth and extract an object from depth Image

Tags: matlab, filtering, depth, smoothing, silhouette

I am using a dataset which provides depth images of human, I need to extract the object from this image or at least remove the other distortion in the image that not belong to the human body In Matlab.

a sample of images is shown below:

[image: Human Body in RED and noise in black colors]

This is the output when I used

```
I = imread ('39.jpg');
human = sum(I,3)>10+10;
```

[human](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRU28.jpg)

Any way to do that please?
thanks in Advance

Comment: So, if you have the human in red, why dont you just segment by colors? Red==human, discard the rest

Comment: because I have thousands of images and the human has different colors in these images! any other way to segment?

Comment: Image processing is not magic, most solutions are problem dependent. If you dont show the entire problem, you are not going to get the entire solution. Are the humans always in color? is the rest always gray? Are there multiple humans in each image? are your images `jgp` or other format?

Comment: The human are all in color and the other is in gray or black. The human has other colors such as green, blue, gray or yellow in many different images. There is only one human per image. The images are all as jpg image.

Comment: OK. Just let me repeat: avoid jpg at all costs. Use png always for scientific data

Comment: Please can you check the output, I have added it in the question I think there is something!

Comment: I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the image you show, where everything is grayscale but something is red, then just do:

```
so=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZOQv.jpg');
human=sum(abs(diff(single(so),1,3)),3)>20;
```

This essentially compares the difference in RGB values of the pixels, and gets the one above a threshold. If you have proper pngs, then the threshold should just be 1, however with jpg artifacts you may need a higher value, for this image 20 does the job.

There are some tiny artefacts in the result image, very likely due to `jpg`. When you do science, you need to store in `png`. If you have absolutely no other choice than `jpg`, then you may have artefacts.

Comment: Thank you so much, does it work if the human has other colors such as green, blue, gray or yellow?

Comment: @Meme depends on the answers to my comment in the questions

Comment: I just added the answer of the above question

Comment: Many Thanks for your help appreciate it

Comment: @Andre Biguri The code stucks with images that contain GRAY or Black silhouette and could not process them. Please any idea?

Comment: @Meme thats a different question

Comment: @Andre Biguri I post the question in a new thread, would you please have a look. Thanks                
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848636/how-to-split-different-silhouettes-colors-from-a-depth-image